# Cycles device settings "GPU Compute" Setting greyed out

Tags: rendering

As described in the title I can`t my rendering device to my graphics card (gtx 980) since the option is greyed out.
I am using Blender 2.8.0 (Also tried to use 2.8.1/ same problem)

Comment: Have you checked if you can enable your GPU in the preferences or if it's listed at all (*Edit > Preferences > System* in the CUDA tab)?

Comment: Thank you, although the graphics card was already selected in the mentioned menu un-/rechecking the card did the job for me